# vibration on Geely Emgrand EC7

Tags: transmission, vibration, cvt-transmission

I have a Geely Emgrand EC7, 2014. It has automatic CVT. I am facing a problem.

Sometimes when I reduce speed and again accelerate, I see vibration and/or slipping in my car. Just like slipping a chain of bicycle during pedal.

Can guide me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know much about CVTs, but it seems to me the belt which drives the CVT is causing you issues. The way that most are designed, they have small metal ribs in the belt. I'd assume when they start slipping, they'd do exactly what you are describing with the vibration. Leaving this as a comment due to my true lack of knowledge on these types of transmissions.